# If $Av=Bv$ for every $v$ then $A=B$ proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone prove this simply to me..? I found two other questions and for some reason couldn't understand the proof. Intuitively if I view both A and B as linear transformations they both transform V the same way so they are equal but I found this:
$$A=AI = A[e_1 \dots e_n] = [Ae_1 \dots Ae_n] \\
B=BI=B[e_1 \dots e_n] = [Be_1 \dots Be_n]$$

so because $Ae_i=Be_i$ we get $A=B$. Here $e_i$ is the $i$th unit coordinate vector.

Maybe I don't understand matrix multiplication or something but how does $A[e_1 \dots e_n]$  turn into $[Ae_1 \dots Ae_n]$ is this even defined?

Comment: Check with a concrete example of a 3x3 matrix. Once you’ve satisfied yourself that $A[e_1,e_2,e_3]=[Ae_1,Ae_2,Ae_3]$ you should see how it is true in general. This is a very fundamental property of matrix multiplication, underpins many operations and ideas we do with them (linearity!)

Comment: What would be $A\neq B$ ? For me there is nothing to prove it's like the definition.

Comment: @zwim This may be true for linear maps, but matrices are not linear maps. They're a collection of numbers with a specific enumeration. But given specific bases of two vector spaces, every matrix can be used to define a linear map in a specific way. The question is about proving that different matrices define different linear maps, which isn't immediately true by definition.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $[e_1\,\ldots\,\ e_n]$ denotes the $n\times n$ matrix whose first column is $e_1$, whose second column is $e_2$ and so on. That's why $I=[e_1\,\ldots\,\ e_n]$, and therefore $AI=A[e_1\,\ldots\,\ e_n]=[Ae_1\,\ldots\ Ae_n]$. Of course, $[Ae_1\,\ldots\ Ae_n]$ denotes the $n\times n$ matrix whose first column is $Ae_1$, whose second column is $Ae_2$ and so on.

So, since $[Ae_1\,\ldots\ Ae_n]=[Be_1\,\ldots\ Be_n]$, $A=B$.

Comment: At the end you just say So, since $[Ae_1\,\ldots\ Ae_n]=[Be_1\,\ldots\ Be_n]$, $A=B$. how did you get to the fact that  $[Ae_1\,\ldots\ Ae_n]=[Be_1\,\ldots\ Be_n]$ are equal in the first place?

Comment: Like how do I know that $Ae_i=Be_i$ A is some matrix B is some matrix we don't know they're equal yet and we are just multiplying them by the same basis vector $e_{i}$ but how do I know they are equal?

Comment: We have $[Ae_1\ \ldots\ Ae_n]=[Be_1\ \ldots\ Be_n]$ because we are assuming that, for each vector $v$, $Av=Bv$.

Comment: But how is v even related here I didn't see v here at all once here in the proof? And you're assuming that $Av=Bv$ those two matrices are just different representations of $A$ and $B$ and we're assuming that $Av=Bv$ not that $A=B$ straight off the bat

Comment: You wrote in the title of the question that $Av=Bv$ for every $v$. So, I used this assumption. More precisely, I used the fact that $Ae_i=Be_i$ for each $e_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof you may like:

$Av=Bv\implies (A-B)v=0$; holds for all vectors in the vector space to which vector $v$ belongs.This is possible if matrix $(A-B)$ is null matrix i.e. $(A-B)=0\implies A=B.$

Comment: "this is possible if matrix $(A-B)$ is null matrix"... sure, but that's not the question. The question is the converse (also, regarding $A-B=0\implies A=B$, that is a triviality which unfortunately also doesn't answer the question).

Comment: Can't we say $(A-B)v = 0$ for all $v$ $\implies$ $A - B = 0$? I'm guessing that's what he meant.

Comment: The OP is about the confusion in matrix multiplication which is already answered  by AnotherUser. My answer is just another approach to the proof.